# CFWheels -Redirect user if params.key does not exist?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I have a basic controller action, which does a findByKey(). The URL would look like:

/pin/show/45

However, if the '45' is not present (the params.key), I want to redirect them to just /pin/.

At the moment, when no key is specified, it still seems to display the show action with ALL posts. I'm a bit confused on this.

Also, if I do a check in the show() action for params.key, it doesn't work as expected; my redirect does not happen...even though dumping params, shows no key present.

Here's my show() action:

```
public void function show() {

    if( !structKeyExists(params, "key") ) {

        flashInsert( messages = [{ messageString="Key is required.", messageType="error" }] );
        redirectTo(route="pin");

    }

    param name="params.page" default="1";
    param name="params.pageQuantity" default="10";

    pins = model("pin").findByKey(

        key         = params.key,
        returnAs    = "query",
        include     = "user", 
        order       = "createdat DESC",
        page        = params.page,
        perPage     = params.pageQuantity

    );

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Michael.

**Update:**

It seems this may have something to do with routes? Here are my routes for pin, below:

```
addRoute(name="pinShow",        pattern="pin/show/[key]",       controller="pin",       action="show");
addRoute(name="pinEdit",        pattern="pin/edit/[key]",       controller="pin",       action="edit");
addRoute(name="pinDelete",      pattern="pin/delete/[key]",     controller="pin",       action="delete");
addRoute(name="pinUpdate",      pattern="pin/update",           controller="pin",       action="update");
addRoute(name="pinNew",         pattern="pin/new",              controller="pin",       action="new");
addRoute(name="pinCreate",      pattern="pin/create",           controller="pin",       action="create");
addRoute(name="pinWanted",      pattern="pin/wanted",           controller="pin",       action="wanted");
addRoute(name="pin",            pattern="pin",                  controller="pin",       action="index");
```

Now, a lot of these routes may seem pointless as they use the same URL pattern as they would without a route, but the plan is to change these in future.

When I hit /pin/show/, without a key, it seems to load in the /pin/index/ controller and action, but still showing /pin/show/ in the URL.

Comment: Does the code make it into your if statement? Is the key defined, but blank?

Comment: The code in the if statement never executes, regardless of whether or not params.key shows in the struct. Interestingly though, when I dump out params, I see the action is index. So it's almost as if when a record hasn't been found, it simply loads the default action - not what i want, as the URL still shows /pin/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean this up significantly with the [`verifies()`](http://cfwheels.org/docs/function/verifies) initializer.

```
function init() {
  verifies(
    only        = "show",
    params      = "key",
    paramsTypes = "integer",
    handler     = "handleInvalidShowParams"
  );
}

function show() {
  param name="params.page" default="1";
  param name="params.pageQuantity" default="10";

  pins = model("pin").findByKey(
    key      = params.key,
    returnAs = "query",
    include  = "user", 
    order    = "createdat DESC",
    page     = params.page,
    perPage  = params.pageQuantity
  );
}

private function handleInvalidShowParams() {
  flashInsert( messages = [{ messageString="Key is required.", messageType="error" }] );
  redirectTo(route="pin");
}
```

As you can see, we add a check to make sure that `key` is present and is an integer. If either of those tests fail, the controller runs `handleInvalidShowParams()`, which can do whatever you need for it to do.

This keeps the scope of `show()` to what it needs to worry about, and other mechanisms in the controller can worry about parameter validation.

**Update**

Take a look at the 2nd line, which I've added in:

```
addRoute(name="pinShow",   pattern="pin/show/[key]",   controller="pin", action="show");
addRoute(name="pinShow",   pattern="pin/show",         controller="pin", action="show");
addRoute(name="pinEdit",   pattern="pin/edit/[key]",   controller="pin", action="edit");
addRoute(name="pinDelete", pattern="pin/delete/[key]", controller="pin", action="delete");
addRoute(name="pinUpdate", pattern="pin/update",       controller="pin", action="update");
addRoute(name="pinNew",    pattern="pin/new",          controller="pin", action="new");
addRoute(name="pinCreate", pattern="pin/create",       controller="pin", action="create");
addRoute(name="pinWanted", pattern="pin/wanted",       controller="pin", action="wanted");
addRoute(name="pin",       pattern="pin",              controller="pin", action="index");
```

I believe that will catch the `/pin/show` pattern without a key.

As extra credit, I might suggest that you take a look at the [ColdRoute plugin](http://cfwheels.org/plugins/listing/67) and the [accompanying screencast series](http://cfwheels.org/screencasts/series/2) because it makes a lot of this stuff much more trivial.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks. I have used your code but it's still failing to execute the code when the key is missing. The only time it redirects and displays the flash is when the type is of string and not numeric. It appears as though the app is still displaying the /pin/show/ action in the URL, but loading the /pin/index/ action into this. Any idea why this is happening? Is it standard for wheels to fallback on some kind of default action?

Comment: You may want to add another route that catches `pin/show` without a `[key]` and point it to the show action. It's probably falling back to `index` because the lack of key is causing it to match the `index` route. If you need more help, add relevant parts of your `route.cfm` to your question.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated my initial post to show my routes on the /pin/ controller. Any help would be appreciated. It looks fine to me, but maybe it's so obvious that I have become blind to the problem.

Comment: See updated answer. You may want to repeat this method for all routes that have a key value that may be missing.

Comment: Fantastic Chris! As ever, you've been a great help to me. Thank you! Adding in the extra route condition seemed to kick it into the expected behavior.

Comment: Great! Just passing on the knowledge after bugging Per for years. :)